# How to control a Counter Strike(CS 1.6) server which is hosted in a remote location?

Tags: counter-strike, server-administration

I have been playing Counter Strike 1.6 for the last two years; however, it's still interesting to me.
A week ago, I bought a dedicated CS 1.6 server which is hosted in a remote location. They didn't gave any remote access tool to handle that server. Does anyone know about that kind of tool?

**Info About the Server:**

- They are giving around 80 GB of disk space where the CS 1.6 server is installed.
- The remaining space can be used for file storage.
- Separate username & password was given to access the server through a web interface.
- Using that interface I can start or stop or restart the server(This is not enough for me)
- I can also setup the server configuration in there.
- They do have a tool named AMX mod but it costs too much for me for each month.

**What I want to do with the tool is:**

- be able to see the player names using a browser interface or something like that.
- some operations like kicking, banning, and warning.
- ban such that it may be a temporary ban or permanent ban using the player's IP.

Any suggestions, links or knowledge base would be appreciated!

Comment: @BlueRaja Charging for GPL software is certainly not illegal in itself. @StrixVaria If you are able to upload and alter all of the server files then you can install AMX Mod X (or whatever Metamod plugin) free of charge.

Comment: @Lee: You are correct, my bad.  @MaRaVaN:  If you don't have access to change the necessary files to install AMXX yourself, you may want to consider changing server hosts - most hosting companies will let you do this free of charge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is called remote-console, or [rcon](http://www.counter-strike.com/commands/half_life_1/rcon/).  It's built right into the game; to use it, set `rcon_password` to the same value on the server *(in server.cfg)* and client *(in the console)*, then type into the client-console `rcon <command>` for any commands you want to run on the server.

You can use rcon outside of the game, too.  The most popular tool for this is [HLSW](http://hlsw.net/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Jus after the first two lines i started to comment "i know it...". But the finishing touch is what i wanted... Now i am downloading it. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

This site should be helpful: [Counter-Server, The Official CS Server Admin Site](http://server.counter-strike.net/)

Particularly the How-to section.